# Model method to generate the value for a parameter of an attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to create a method inside a model which can be called on a parameter of an attribute to populate it. I thought of doing it this way but it gives me an error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

```py
class Host(User):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Host"
        verbose_name_plural = "Hosts"
    def gen_path(self):
        path = 'static/{userdir}'.format(userdir=self.email)
        os.mkdir(path)
        return path
    hostpic = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Host Profile Image', upload_to=self.gen_path(), null=True)
```

What could be a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create method that takes `instance` and `filename` as parameter for `upload_to` attribute;

```
def gen_path(instance, filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]
    filename = f"{instance.email}.{extension}"
    return f"static/{filename}"


class Host(User):
    hostpic = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Host Profile Image', upload_to=gen_path, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Host"
        verbose_name_plural = "Hosts"
```

for more information [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :

You should insert a folder name to save images like :-

```
hostpic = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Host Profile Image', upload_to='hostimages', null=True)
```

Comment: No, I need the save path to be dynamic.