# Django how to get model values inside another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I want the value of username from forms that I get as a string so that when I upload an image it is stored in a subdirectory with that username.
i.e. if 'bob' registers the image should be saved in 'static/auth_image/bob/image_name.extension'.
Also if I could it during the registration form filling that would be great.

models.py

```
class User_data(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    four_digit_pass = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    private_key = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/profilepic', null=True)
    def getUsername(self):
        return self.username

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
    
class AuthImages(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User_data', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    uname=owner.
    def save_auth_image(self):
        uname = self.username
        self.auth_image_file = models.ImageField(
            upload_to='static/auth_image/%s' % uname, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    four_digit_pass = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User_data
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'four_digit_pass',
                  'profile_pic', 'private_key']
```

register.html

```
{% extends "storage_app/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Register Page</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}
        <p>Private Key should not be changed or shared with anyone</p>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock body_block %}
```

here in HTML, i want to take input for the second i.e. auth_image directly from webcam if possible

This is my first question also I am new to Django so please help me out if there is a cleaner way to write this and please excuse any mistakes.

Comment: hi, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66205289/10170918 this answer should help you. you can use `upload_to` attribute for dynamic path in ImageField.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Model method to generate the value for a parameter of an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66203781/model-method-to-generate-the-value-for-a-parameter-of-an-attribute)